# Display items from json file in an alert (sweetalert) jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am using sweetalert for alerts and want to display some data from an adjacent .json file in a sweetalert alert with jQuery. The json file has 5 items and in a seperate attempt using getJSON I managed to display the first 2 so I am trying the $ajax method to do more. The current code I have just goes right down to the "always" function and displays "complete" in the alert, it doesn't display the success method. So I would like to know how to alter the code to display the items in the alert.

The code is below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '#json', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'somedata.json',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {param1: 'value1'}
    })
    .done(function() {
      swal("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
      swal("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
      swal("complete");
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try somthings like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '#json', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'somedata.json',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {param1: 'value1'}
      })
    .done(function(data) {
     data.each(el,function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
      swal(el);
     },300);
        });
       });
      });
     });
```

**EDIT**

from this bug report you have to set time between instances [Source](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/issues/472)

Comment: I tried that, the alert doesn't show at all. Thanks anyway.